# how to get the exact latlng value in android

Tags: android, android-maps

i want to get the latlng value base on user input address for e.g. limda chowk, rajkot, gujarat, india.

but i am not getting perfect latlng value.

if i pass the street like limda chowk, subhash road, rajkot, gujarat, india,
then it'll give me the latlng center of the street.

i want that particular latlng of that location how can i get this think in android

here is my code for that

```
public static String getLatLng(Context context,String addr){
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    String add;
    try{
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addr, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        add = obj.getAddressLine(0);

        add = add + "\nCountryName " + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\nCountryCode " + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\nAdminArea " + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\nPostalCode " + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\nSubAdminArea " + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\nFeatureName " + obj.getFeatureName();
        add = add + "\nLocality " + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();
        add = add + "\nurl " + obj.getUrl();
        add = add + "\nLatitude " + obj.getLatitude();
        add = add + "\nLongitude " + obj.getLongitude();

        //Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        add = e.toString();
    }
    return add;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I got the answer for my question that was, google not store the all the address for the area like wise here in my question "limda chowk", because it's not too famous or not important with the nearest other place like "sastriya medan". If I want to exact latlng of the place I need to create my own database, collect the addresses information and store into this database with appropriate latlng value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Get [Latitude and Logitude from Address, android](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/get-locationlatitude-and-longitude-from.html)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: i want to find the latlng base on address not based on latlng itself